# Fulltext $text query extremely slow in mongo 3.0.1

Tags: php, mongodb

After doing ~5K fulltext RPS on a single Mongo 2.4.5 using $command, our newely upgraded Mongo 3.0.1 crashes at less than 1K fulltext RPS using $text.

Both are running Ubuntu 12.04 (3.13.0-48-generic Trusty Kernel), using SSD and the latest PHP 5.5 driver (1.6.6).

We tried:

- WiredTiger instead of the default engine
- No compression instead of Snappy
- Removing Scores/Ranking from Fulltext
- V1 instead of V2 fulltext version

Anyone experienced Mongo 3.0.1 with this kind of fulltext load?

Comment: What does it say in the logs when it crashes? Can you show us an example of the documents and the queries you send? Have you tried with the current version of text indexes? If not, why not?

Comment: I've formatted the drive a few times so don't have access to logs, but I believe it was standard SIG 15 fault. The documents are pretty small with fulltext index on the _id itself. The criteria is as defined http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/text/#op._S_text. We did try both the V1 TextIndex and V2.

Comment: We'll need to see some documents, the query, and the message in the logs to get anywhere. Can you reproduce the problem (ideally as minimally as possible) and gather all that information? If it crashes with a stack trace, that shouldn't happen and you should [file a JIRA ticket](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER) about the problem. Also, does this happen just with WiredTiger or with either storage engine?

Comment: i'll get some logs for you. as mentioned i've tried both wiredtiger and the default engine with the same result. 2.4 doesn't have this problem. it seems like basic slowness in getting fulltext queries, which (in 5K RPS) accumulate connections quite rapidly.